# Show/Hide(toggle) several blocks via Angular template engine

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i need to show one and hide others.
in jquery i used 'this':

```
$('div').click(functiuon(){ this.show() });
```

maybe in Angular we can you use something like that?

```html
<div class="toggle">
  <span ng-click="this=!this ? true : false"></span><br/>
  <span ng-if="this" >
    111111111
  </span>
</div>
<div class="toggle">
  <span ng-click="this=!this ? true : false"></span><br/>
  <span ng-if="this" >
    2222222222222
  </span>
</div>
etc this, this , this
```

I need to use only one varible for all blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any dom element interaction like clicking an element should be done within the directive and you can follow this to achieve what you want:

```js
var app = angular.module('demoapp', []);

app.directive('toggleIt', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
      console.log(el.find('span'));
      el.find('span').eq(0).on('click', function() {
        el.find('span').eq(1).toggleClass('hide show');
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.show{display:block;}
.hide{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='demoapp'>
  <div data-toggle-it class="toggle">
    <span>toggle1</span>
    <br/>
    <span class='spn show'>
    111111111
  </span>
  </div>
  <div data-toggle-it class="toggle">
    <span>toggle2</span>
    <br/>
    <span class='spn hide'>
    2222222222222
  </span>
  </div>
  <div data-toggle-it class="toggle">
    <span>toggle3</span>
    <br/>
    <span class='spn hide'>
    3333333333333
  </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, Could i use only one function for all <div class="toggle"> and show/hide each of them separatly?

Comment: coz i will have a few dozens <div class="toggle">  and to make for each new function and varible it's crazy

Comment: @AxOn check this one, if you want to do this with in directive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-hide` for hiding an element on true or `ng-show` for showing an element on true:

```
<div class="toggle">
  <span ng-click="pop1=!pop1 ? true : false"></span><br/>
  <span ng-show="pop1" >
    111111111
  </span>
</div>
<div class="toggle">
  <span ng-click="pop2=!pop2 ? true : false"></span><br/>
  <span ng-show="pop2" >
    2222222222222
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: i changed example, maybe now more clearly, what i want

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ng-if**, **ng-show**, **ng-hide**, **ng-class** (in conjunction with css), and **ng-switch**.

**ng-show**, **ng-hide** and **ng-if** have kind of the same logic behind them (if the given variable is true/false, show/hide the following content). There are some performance differences between them, but this subject is out of scope.

Showing/hiding elements with **ng-class** is just a particular use case of it, but its achievable nonetheless.

To sum it up, **ng-hide**, **ng-show**, **ng-if** hide/show elements based on the truth evaluation of a given variable, while **ng-class** toggles a class, like

```
$('#someElement').toggleClass('randomClassName');
```

Example:

HTML

```
<div ng-app="exampleApp" ng-init="switchr1 = true; switchr2 = true; switchr3 = true; switchr4 = show; ">
  <h2>ng-if</h2>
  <div class="toggle">
    <span ng-click="switchr1 = switchr1 ? false : true">click me</span><br/>
    <span ng-if="switchr1" >
      shown by ng-if
    </span>
  </div>

  <h2>ng-show</h2>
  <div class="toggle">
    <span ng-click="switchr2 = switchr2 ? false : true">click me</span><br/>
    <span ng-show="switchr2" >
      shown by ng-show
    </span>
  </div>


  <h2>ng-hide</h2>
  which is the same thing as ng-show, but with reversed logic<br>
  <div class="toggle">
    <span ng-click="switchr3 = switchr3 ? false : true">click me</span><br/>
    <span ng-hide="!switchr3" >
      shown by ng-hide
    </span>
  </div>

  <h2>ng-class</h2>

  <div class="toggle">
    <span ng-click="switchr4 = (switchr4=='show') ? 'hide' : 'show'">click me</span><br/>
    <span ng-class="switchr4" >
      hidden by ng-class
    </span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Notice, that you initiate switchr1, switchr2 and so on in the ng-init directive. You could have also done that in the js code, using $scope, but I did it this way for the sake of simplicity.

JS

```
var app = angular.module('exampleApp', []);
```

CSS

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: initial;
}
```

I also wrote some working code/full example for you:
http://codepen.io/VanTudor/pen/EKYZwM